# Typescript binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Typescript now and i have problem that when i want to do getLocation() function, i want to assign str which declared out of this function to latitude + longitude which is compute in getLocation() function.But it always said that str is undefined.I do not know why.Can some one help me? Thanks!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-center',
  templateUrl: './center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./center.component.css']
})
export class CenterComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: Observable<any>;
  locationInfo: any;
  str: any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  location() {
    this.getLocation();
    //console.log(this.str);
    //this.getInfor();
  }
  getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPostion.bind(this), this.showError.bind(this));
    }
  }
  showPostion(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    this.str = String(latitude + ',' + longitude);
    console.log(this.str);
  }
  showError() {
    console.log('Invalid Address !');
  }
  getInfor() {
    this.dataSource = this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
      + 'latlng=' + this.str + '&key=<mykey>').map(Response => Response.json());
    this.dataSource.subscribe(
      data => this.locationInfo = data
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with Angular 2 and Typescript, but I don't understand when `this.str` gets set. I see that it gets set in `showPostion`, which gets called by `getLocation`, which gets called by `location`, which gets called where?

Comment: The code seems ok, did you log the `position` variable to see what it contains when `showPosition` is called? Of course `str` is empty in the `location()` method, since `getLocation` did not return anything yet. You could init your component with `str : string = "finding position"` to make sure it's never undefined.

Answer (score 2):

To autobind you can use arrows:

```
location() {
```

becomes:

```
location = () => {
```

## More

Arrow functions https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: I'm still confused about bind.I just want to assign the global "str" to the value that get in getLocation() as in java.But it does not work in Typescript.Do you have any idea how to change the code?Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It's a neat syntax but I don't see how this answers the question, since you're just suggesting a different way to bind `this` when it was being bound fine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this` is in scope everywhere that you use it, so I guess the issue is that `this.str` is accessed before it has been assigned a value.

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, and fires the callback to set the position on success.

You haven't shown us when `this.getInfor` gets called (perhaps it's obvious to someone familiar with angular) but I suspect that it is before the callback has been fired, so `this.str` has not yet been assigned a value.

So the solution would be to rearrange the code so the `this.str` was assigned a value before you try to access it.

Comment: You mean I need to assign a value for "str"? But when i do this and then i use location().When i log "str", it is still the value i assigned before, rather the value i expected to be.I expect that "str" should be the value in showPosition().Simply, I just want to make "str" global as in java so that i can use it anywhere.Do you have any suggestion?Thanks~